# Covariance annotation raises incorrect implicit ambiguity error

Tags: scala, covariance, implicit

The code below raises an implicit not found error that the `-Xlog-implicits` sbt option explains as an ambiguity, which I pasted at the end:

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait JsonOFormat[T]
trait BsonOFormat[T]

trait Codec[CTXO[_]]

implicit def jsonCodec: Codec[JsonOFormat] = new Codec[JsonOFormat] {}
implicit def bsonCodec: Codec[BsonOFormat] = new Codec[BsonOFormat] {}

trait CApply[T,N,+CTXO[_]] {
  def apply(t: T): CTXO[N] = ???
}
object CApply {
  class CApplyBuilder[CTXO[_]] {
    def instance[T,N](implicit cApply: CApply[T,N, CTXO]) = new CApply[T,N,CTXO] {}
  }
  def ctx[CTXO[_]]: CApplyBuilder[CTXO] = new CApplyBuilder[CTXO]

  implicit def default[T,N,CTXO[_]](implicit hc: Codec[CTXO]): CApply[T, N, CTXO] = new CApply[T,N,CTXO] {}
}

CApply.ctx[JsonOFormat].instance[String,Int]

//Information:(23, 34) A$A261.this.CApply.default is not a valid implicit 
//value for A$A261.this.CApply[String,Int,A$A261.this.JsonOFormat] because:
//hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
 //both method bsonCodec in class A$A261 of type => A$A261.this.Codec[A$A261.this.BsonOFormat]
 //and method jsonCodec in class A$A261 of type => A$A261.this.Codec[A$A261.this.JsonOFormat]
 //match expected type A$A261.this.Codec[CTXO]
//CApply.ctx[JsonOFormat].instance[String,Int]
                            ^
```

The explanation is saying that my `CTXO` was left for the compiler to be solved (infered) as a parameter. But that's not correct I explicitly set `JsonOFormat` as `CTXO`.

Of course as with most of such cases removing that covariance annotation on `CApply[T,N,+CTXO[_]]` makes the error go away. But the rest of my library as it is now depends on that annotation. is there a solution to keep both the Scala compiler and me happy at the same time?